# Dado rail joining

Tags: carpentry

I want to put a dado rail up my staircase. The staircase turns as it goes up. There are three walls as you ascend. One on the left, one in front of you and one after you turn right to get to the top. How do I join ascending dado on the internal corners please.

Comment: Same way you join any two pieces of wood at a corner: with a miter. If you want a more detailed answer, you'll probably have to give us more details, like a picture of a corner, a drawing of the pieces, angles of the corners involved, etc.

Comment: Probably the most fun kind of miter, the **compound** miter.